# Getting the warning: ' In function ‘void dfs(int)’ Warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am working on a simple DFS problem where I have to return the number of respective child nodes having more child nodes as compared to their parents (Child nodes>Parent nodes:Count++).

I have been facing the problem I mentioned in the title and I haven't been able to work around it. I used unsigned int too, but to no avail. I am clear with my logic for this question, but fairly new to coding and hence face difficulties with errors such as this. I will attach only my DFS function below, where the problem seems to be occurring. Please help me with this. (Using adjacency list)

```
vector<int> adj[100001];
bool visited[100001]={false};
int parent=0;
int child=INT_MAX;
int counterr=0;

/*Recursive DFS:*/

void dfs(int s){
    child=adj[s].size()-1;
    if(child>parent)
        counterr++;
    if(s==1)
        parent=adj[s].size();
    else
        parent=adj[s].size()-1;
    visited[s]=true;
    for(int i=0;i<adj[s].size();i++)
    {
        if(visited[adj[s][i]==false])
            dfs(adj[s][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `size()` returns an unsigned type. `int` is a signed type. Comparing them will cause the warning. Also, `size()-1` will wrap to a very large value on an empty vector

Comment: because std::containers use size_t (which are unsined) for indices and you are using int.
In the for loop you are comparing a int so the size_t that is returned by size()

Comment: use `size_t` type instead of `int` for `.size()` comparations.

Comment: You may use `std::distance(adj[s].begin(), adj[s].end());` which returns a signed integer.

Comment: @Ruks Yes this helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, you can ignore this. However, if your integer exceeds the normal integer limit, or your adj[s] vector is empty, this may become a problem. If parent is never negative you can just change the line

```cpp
int parent;
```

to

```cpp
unsigned int parent;
```

which will completely prevent this warning.

Comment: I did declare the varaible parent as an unsigned integer, but that still didn't help.

Comment: There may be other comparisons in the code where a similar problem occurs.

Comment: Like in `for(int i=0;i<adj[s].size();i++)`

Comment: Yes that seemed to be the problem. I changed the way the vector size was declared. By using the distance() function to find the size.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<adj[s].size();i++)
```

You get this warning because `adj[s].size()` is unsigned integer, but `i` is signed.

For fix that warning use this instead, and `i` became unsigned.

```
for (size_t i=0; i < adj[s].size(); i++)
```